# Генерация случайной строки СИ

Tags: c

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы генерировалась случайная строка до 30 элементов с поддержкой русского, английского и символов. Знаю про функцию rand(), но она же работает только с числами(или нет?). Спасибо!

Comment: Любые данные в **цифр**овом формате – числа. просто генерируйте их в нужном диапазоне и смело присваивайте `char`-у.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [пример](https://ideone.com/Dobcxe) для больших букв английского алфавита.

```
char s[10] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) s[i] = rand()%26+'A';
```

Как распространить на маленькие, русские и т.д. - понятно?

Comment: Да, все понял, спасибо большое!)